# Unable to get the value of 2 textboxes

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

I'm trying to get the value of 2 textboxes with Javascript.

Textbox 1, nothing wrong.

Textbox 2, same code, but nothing happens.

Here is the code

```
var fieldname;
fieldname = document.getElementById("div"+field).getAttribute("field");

alert(fieldname);    // RETURNS "Birthdate"
var textval;

textval = document.getElementById("textfield"+field).value;
alert(textval);      // RETURNS NOTHING
```

`var field` is the id of the textbox and `div`.

**Why isn't this working?**

Comment: A vital part of your code is missing - where is the HTML??? Can you post that as well?

Comment: Can you please share your HTML?

Also "problem" isn't a very good tag; I'll remove that one for ya.

Comment: Yet we have 49 questions with the tag.

Comment: Hey, I didn't claim it wasn't used elsewhere.

Comment: @Dean - It was more of an observation as to how we have 49 questions with a unhelpful, superfluous tag.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: we now have 10 fewer.  Woosh.

Comment: @Dean - Now you have me feeling guilty for not doing some volunteer cleanup! *Guilt is how you get things done!*

Answer (score 6):

When posting html/javascript/css problems like this, isolate the code and put it in a jsfiddle ( [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) ).  Not only will this allow others to much more quickly solve your problem for you, but often isolating the code from your environment cuts out extra factors that may have been causing unexpected behavior.  Often the process of moving a snippet to jsfiddle.net can show the problem before anyone else even needs to get involved!

Secondly, I recommend modifying your debugging practices to make it easier on yourself than using alerts:

- Run a browser with a js console.
- Log debugging to console.log()
- To ensure graceful degredation of console.log, add this code to your global javascript:

  if (typeof(console) == 'undefined') { console = { log: function() { } }; }
- Run js in the console to check for values where something goes wrong in the static code, e.g.

  - run `document.getElementById("textfield"+field).value` to check whether the value you expect is available, and then walk back down the line if you don't find what you're expecting, e.g. if `.value` isn't available, run `document.getElementById("textfield"+field)` and expand the object to view it's contents, etc.
- You can also run any arbitrary javascript of your choice in the console, with clickable access to the available javascript objects created by the page loading.  This somewhat lessens the need for manually coding in alerts as well.

Comment: Seriously, the days when `alert` was your only option are way behind us!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="div<?php echo $aantal;?>" field="<?php echo $rows['field'];?>">
                            <h3><?php echo $rows['name'];?>:</h3>
                            <p id="p<?php echo $aantal;?>">
                                <input type="text" id="textfield<?php echo $aantal;?>" value="<?php echo $rows['default'];?>" MAXLENGTH="<?php echo $rows['length'];?>"/><br/>
                                <input type="button" id="buttonacc<?php echo $aantal;?>" value="Verzend" onClick="acc('<?php echo $aantal;?>');"/>
                                <input type="button" id="buttonden<?php echo $aantal;?>" value="Nu niet!" onClick="den('<?php echo $aantal;?>');"/>
                            </p>
</div>
```

This is the HTML

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript:var val = 1;alert(document.getElementById("textfield"+val).value)
```

When i use this code in the javaconsole of firefox, nothing wrong!